# write a "macro" to launch multiple terminal windows with one icon

Tags: terminal, automator

I have to send a sales person to a conference, and I have a mack set up with a MEAN app (running mongo and node app in browser), I don't want my sales person to have to know/worry about how to launch mongo, or the node server, I want a way to let them click on an icon - and it will launch a terminal window that starts mongo, and launches a terminal window that starts node, and launches the web browser to the correct address.

Is there a way to do this?

The commands desired:

Terminal #1

> mongod --dbpath=Desktop/Demo/data/db

Terminal #2

> cd Desktop/Demo/api
>
> nodemon

Terminal #3

> cd Desktop/Demo/ui
>
> nodemon

Browser

> localhost:3000

Comment: There sure is. Can you add the commands you are currently using to the question?

Comment: Have you looked at Automator? In the applications folder... Have a look at : https://www.lifewire.com/automate-opening-applications-and-folders-on-mac-2260908

Comment: Is there any specific need for the different windows, e.g. do the users afterwards need to read generated output?

Answer (score 1):

I would make each script be saved to a plain text file and you can name them 1 and 2 and 3 and 4 and put them in a folder.

When you name a plain text file abc.command, clicking it runs the script.

I'd also use https://brew.sh to install mongodb so you can just use `brew services` to run that at launch. It's likely lightweight and you could have a "restart" script in case the demo goes south.

Also - teach your sales people, this is an easy thing to understand and imaging how much better they can sell when they say - I know tech and I know how to run and manage not only the product we're selling but own the demo requirements. Good luck in your venture.